I'm trying to set my Mac's Menu Bar automatically with the `defaults` command, but it doesn't work
I am new to the defaults command.
It confuses me a lot. Sometimes it doesn't work but the com.apple.xxx domain has changed successfully.
Now I want to set my menu bar automatically. I find it stored in the com.apple.controlcenter. Just like this.

Then I create a new account to test if my command is correct. But it doesn't work.
The command is below.
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible WiFi" -bool false
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible Bluetooth" -bool false
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible AirDrop" -bool false
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible FocusModes" -bool false
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible ScreenMirroring" -bool false
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible Sound" -bool true
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible AccessibilityShortcuts" -bool false
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible Battery" -bool true
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible Clock" -bool false

# And I tried like this too
defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible WiFi" 0
...


I don't know the reason. Is there anyone who can help me?

The Control Centre is a different thing from the menubar. The CC is one item on the menubar. Are you trying to add menulet items to the menubar?

Hi,I had two test to find that menu bar is indeed belong to Control Centre.
In the first test,I used apple script to click menu bar icon and it works.
tell application "System Events"
 tell process "ControlCenter"
  tell menu bar 1
   click menu bar item "Clock"
  end tell
 end tell
end tell

Screen Shot 2024-05-22 at 08.55.55.jpeg

You may need to configure com.apple.systemuiserver.plist as well.

Sry for my previous confusing comment,I can't paste image, and the code block is strange.
I use defaults read com.apple.systemuisever.plist and it says "Domain com.apple.systemuisever.plist does not exist".What should I do?Touch one manually?

server, not sever.

Oh,thank you very much.
